# Laravel - What is the convention for two parts names in polymorphisms?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, conventions

The name convention for polymorphism concept in Laravel is like this below:

For example for `comment` we use `commentable`, but what do we use for two parted names like `foo_bar`? should it be changed to `foo_barable`, `fooBarable` or `foobarable`?

Comment: I believe there is no such convention because the usage of polymorphic relationship is to be many to many, so in your case the polymorphic relationship should be `typeable` I guess and either `foo` or `bar` should have types.

Comment: FWIW, with Laravel, I think the best practice is to do your best to be clever with names such that you can avoid 2-part names whenever possible.